# calculating the time to travel to a geocoordinate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

If i have 2 `geo-positions` ( `longitude` and `latitude` ) can i calculate the time taken to travel from `location1` to `location2` ? How can i implement this?

```
CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:@"xxxxxxx" longitude:@"xxxxxxx"];
  CLLocation *loc2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:@"xxxxxx" longitude:@"xxxxxx"];
```

these are the only code i have, how do i calculate the time taken?

I know another method where i could come up with the time. Its `Distance Between the 2 location / Speed`.

But is there any other way i could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time to travel how? It's straightforward to compute the straight line distance; then the time to travel that "as the crow flies" is simple division.

But if you mean by road, you're going to have to get more information than you have; you need a route, the length of each leg, and the potential speed.

(You're going to need some trig for this, but remember you have a right triangle on the surface of a sphere, about 4000 miles in radius.  Here's [an example](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).)